# Unmarshall XML element that occurs more than once using JAXB

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal XML document into my model. The issue is that I have one XML element `<additional_detail>` that occurs more than once in the XML document. When I unmarshal the XML document, the JSON element has the value of the last occurrence of `<additional_detail>`. What I am trying to achieve is having them all comma-separated maybe.

Exampple of document

```
.
.
.
<additional_detail>
 160cm
</additional_detail>
<additional_detail>
200KG
</additional_detail>
.
.
.
```

and I have in my java model:

> ```
> @XmlElement(name = "additional_detail", namespace = NAME_SPACE)
> private String additionalDetail;
> ```

Comment: use list of string , then from there you can generate CSV or what you want
https://ibytecode.com/blog/jaxb-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-of-objects/
or google jaxb xml to list of objects will provide you plenty of solution

Comment: This case is a bit different, the case I am talking about, all the occurrences of the element are on the root level and not grouped under one element called <additional-details> for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hopefully below example can help

xml

```
    <Example>
    <detail>1</detail>
    <detail>2</detail>
    <detail>3</detail>
    </Example>
```

code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class JaxBUnmarshalExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Example.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Example que = (Example) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(que.details);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Example")
class Example { 
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<String>();
    String detail;  
    @XmlElement(name = "detail")
    public String getDetail() {     
        return detail;
    }
    /*
     here adding items in list later list can be used  
    */ 
    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        details.add(detail);
        this.detail = detail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment you should use the `List` to capture all the information which have the same tags in XML. Following is the example which shows the example of the similar xml:

XML:

```
<root>
    <additional_detail>160cm</additional_detail>
    <additional_detail>200KG</additional_detail>
</root>
```

Parent.class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {
    @XmlElement(name = "additional_detail")
    List<String> additional_detail;
}
```

Main.class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("action.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final Parent parent = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Parent.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(parent.toString());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(parent, System.out);
    }
}
```

If in case you have the outer tags for those lists something like `additional_details` (observe the 's') then you can do something like this:

```
<root>
    <additional_details>
        <additional_detail>160cm</additional_detail>
        <additional_detail>200KG</additional_detail>
    </additional_details>
</root>
```

Parent.class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "additional_details")
    @XmlElement(name = "additional_detail")
    List<String> additional_detail;
}
```